# Moodle - calling web service returns error/restore_not_executable_awaiting_required

Tags: moodle

I'm stuck with this error.
Trying to call custom web service, that performs duplication of quiz (duplicate_module()), its editation (quiz_update_instance()) and finally cache clearance (rebuild_course_cache).

It works perfectly until I add an question to the quiz. Then it returns error:

```
error/restore_not_executable_awaiting_required | ERRORCODE: restore_not_executable_awaiting_required. Fault code: 78563441. Actual reply from server: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <methodResponse><fault><value><struct><member><name>faultCode</name><value><int>78563441</int></value></member><member><name>faultString</name><value><string>error/restore_not_executable_awaiting_required | ERRORCODE: restore_not_executable_awaiting_required</string></value></member></struct></value></fault></methodResponse>
```

Server settings:

```
max_execution_time=14400
max_input_time=14400
```

Code:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array( 'method' => "POST", 'header' => "Content-Type: text/xml", 'content' => $request, 'timeout' => 14000000, ))); 
$path = $this->url . "/webservice/xmlrpc/server.php?wstoken=" . $this->token; 
$file = file_get_contents($path, false, $context);
```

Could you please help me find the cause of the error? Thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue ?

Comment: In my case it was a permission problem, the user restoring the backup didn't have the capabilities 'moodle/question:managecategory' nor 'moodle/question:add'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading Moodle 3.1 to 3.5.1, and found a fix for this on Moodle 3.5.2, which I cherry-picked:
https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-62897